# Delete rows from one workbook based on data in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I extract 2 database reports that export in Excel tables. I have to remove rows from reportA based on data that already exists in reportA.

(Example: If Column 5 contains the word "*Pepsi*" in any cell of that column, delete the entire row in reportA)

I have to also remove rows from reportA based on data that exists in a specific column in reportB. So if any cell in a specific column of reportA contains the exact cell value from a specific column in reportB based on key words, delete that row in reportA.

(Example: Filter any cell in Column 4 of reportB containing the word "*Coke*" or "*Sprite*", reportB has matches of "Coke Zero" and "Sprite Shipment" in 2 cells in Column 4. Delete EVERY row from reportA that contains "Coke Zero" or "Sprite Shipment" in Column 5 of reportA)

Did a bit of research and came up with the below script to at least remove rows from reportA.

```
Sub Clean_Up_Food_Items()

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Dim lo As ListObject

   Set lo = Sheet2.ListObjects(1)
   lo.Parent.Activate 'Activate sheet that table is on.

   lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

   lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Coke*"

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False       
     lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

   lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Fanta*"

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The above works to at least remove rows based on data that exists in reportA, but I can't figure out how to filter out the data based on reportB to remove rows in reportA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several values at once in the filter. To use several values in the filter, you need to use 1) 1-D array for criteria and 2) `xlFilterValues` enumeration value for `Operator` parameter. In the example below I filter first column of range A1 with two values.
[image: IMG1]

```
Sub Z()

    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim arrValuesToFilter As Variant

    arrValuesToFilter = [{"Fanta", "Pepsi"}]
    Set rngA = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rngA.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arrValuesToFilter, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup tips JohnyL. Sorry since I'm trying to grasp how to apply this to my worksheets, but can the "Field" section contain multiple values? Also, I would need to compare results from one column first, delete the rows, clear the search filters, then repeat. Similar to what I did in my not-so-clean script above to make sure its not filtering by all values at once if that makes sense.

Comment: *can the "Field" section contain multiple values* If you need several fields, then add such filter for every field.